# remove first match from string in javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I have string like this `'set , many, like, see, what'`

when i create this string i also create `div` with linked element

```
<div>
    <a href="#">set</a>
    <a href="#">many</a>
    <a href="#">like</a>
...
</div>
```

and also create hidden input with `'set , many, like, see, what'` value ... when we click on linked element we have string of link ( example: `set` )
how remove first match of string and strip it from hidden input?

ps: i said first match because one element can repeat

Comment: This type of thing is best done by using a JavaScript library.  Writing it in raw JavaScript takes a lot of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where `link` is a reference to one of the links, `theString` is a reference to your string, and `hidden` is a reference to your hidden input control, you can do something like this:

```
link.onclick = function(e)
{
    var expr = new RegExp("\b" + this.innerHTML + "\b(, ?)?");
    theString = theString.replace(expr, "");
    hidden.value = theString;
}
```

Comment: not work probably, i was enter 'sad' but response list were 'sad, test'

Answer (score 1):

```
var anchors = document.getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName('a'),
    hiddenInput = document.getElementById('hidden');

for (var i = 0, anchorsLength = anchors.length; i < anchorsLength; i++) {

   var anchor = anchors[i];

   anchor.onclick = function() {
      var term = anchor.innerHTML;
      hiddenInput.value = hiddenInput
                          .value
                          .replace(new RegExp(term + ',\s?'), '');
   }

}
```

This code allows you to click one of those anchors, in which it will remove the first occurrence of the anchor's text node, and the `,` and any optional whitespace character.

Comment: not work probably, i was enter 'sad' but response list were 'sad, test'